# need help sending command to server by ssh python

Tags: python

I am trying to connect to the server via ssh and dump the "df- h" output in some text file.

```
p=pexpect.spawn('ssh some.some.com')

i=p.expect([ssh_newkey,'password:',pexpect.EOF])
if i==0:
    print "I say yes"
    p.sendline('yes')
    i=p.expect([ssh_newkey,'password:',pexpect.EOF])
if i==1:
    p.sendline("somesome")
    p.expect(pexpect.EOF)
    i = p.sendline('df -h > /home/test/output.txt')
    print i
    response = p.before
    print response

print p.before
```

I am trying to connect to the server and dump the server data in some text file.
My problem is i = p.sendline('df -h > /home/test/output.txt') is not doing anything,
Basically my output file is empty.
Please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the text file to be created on the computer where you're running the Python program, or on the computer you SSH'd into?

Comment: On the computer I ssh'd into.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) to manage operations over an SSH connection.

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is `i = p.sendline('df -h >
>   /home/test/output.txt')` is not doing
>   anything

Isn't it setting `i` to 29?  Is that what you mean?

> Basically my output file is empty.

How do you *know* that?  Nothing in this code is checking whether that file exists on the remote machine.

> Please help me out.

Does your user on the remote machine have permission to write to the `/home/test` directory there, indeed, does that directory even exist?  You're really giving us too few hints at exactly what you're doing, in exactly what context, and what exactly happens as a result, to be of any help yet, except for peppering you with such questions hoping you'll eventually *tell* us the many crucial pieces of data you're simply omitting.  Help us help you out!-)

Answer (score 1):

If you find yourself doing a lot of work over ssh to the same machines then you may want to look into something like [func](https://fedorahosted.org/func/).

Comment: It's mostly "done"; there are some changes that take place here and there in the code, but once "do this on another machine" works, there isn't much else to write.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using Python as a shell here. Why don't you just save the relevant commands in a bash file and run that in one command instead? I think that'd work out a lot better. I also recommend that you enable SSH publickey authentication, it works better than passwords. Use the `subprocess` module to spawn processes from inside Python.

I guess this advice isn't helpful if you actually need to do things this way for some reason.